# Cделать подключение к вновь созданной таблице и записать туда все данные

Tags: python, openpyxl

Немного расскажу как код работает (полностью его скидывать нет смысла, наверно). Есть zip архивы, в них есть файлы pdf и xml. Распаковываю в несуществующую директорию (она создается при распаковке) pdf файлы и переименовываю их, получая наименование из xml файла. Директория папок выглядит так: `"F:\python_1\minimushestvo\PDF\plans\городской округ г. Выкса"`. Помимо Выксы есть еще 50 других папок, и в каждой папке мне нужно сделать excel, потом записать туда данные из xml файла.

Вот часть кода, сначала укажу полностью, потом опишу его:

```
for path in Path(r'C:\Users\shirshov\Downloads').rglob('*.zip'):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path, mode="r") as archive:
        with archive.open([_ for _ in archive.namelist() if _.endswith(find_xml)][0]) as line: # Находим все xml в архиве
            soup = BeautifulSoup(line.read(), features="xml")
            cad_n = '_'.join((soup.select_one('object common_data cad_number').text).split(':'))
            file_newname_pdf = cad_n + '_' + find_pdf
            if soup.select_one('room_record location_in_build level plans') is not None:
                cad_number = (':'.join((soup.select_one('object common_data cad_number').text).split(':')[:-1]))
                if Name_MO()[0] == 'городской округ г. Выкса':
                    plans_pdf = r'F:\python_1\minimushestvo\PDF\plans\городской округ г. Выкса'
                    extract()
                    file_xlsx = os.path.join(r'minimushestvo\PDF\plans\городской округ г. Выкса', dest_filename)
                    if not os.path.isfile('list.xlsx'):
                        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
                        wb.save(file_xlsx)
                    list_ = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_xlsx)
                    list_sheet = list_.active
                    list_sheet['A1'] = 'Кадастровый номер'
                    list_sheet['B1'] = 'Адрес'
                    list_sheet['C1'] = 'Площадь кв.м.'
                    list_sheet['D1'] = 'Инвентарный номер'
                    list_sheet['E1'] = 'Наименование'
                    list_sheet['F1'] = 'Этажность'
                    list_sheet['G1'] = 'Кадастровый номер родителя'
                    
                    for r in dataframe_to_rows(data_pd(), index=False, header=False):
                        list_sheet.append(r)
                    list_.save(file_xlsx)
```

В строке - `if Name_MO()[0] == 'городской округ г. Выкса':`, есть функция - `Name_MO()[0]`, которая сравнивает переменную - `"cad_number"` с БД и делит по району.

Далее, если есть такой район, создается директория и распаковывается туда pdf через функцию `extract()`.

Далее, в строке - `if not os.path.isfile('list.xlsx'):` идет проверка, есть ли в этой директории `list.xlsx` и, если нет, он создается.

Далее, в строке - `list_ = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_xlsx)` идет подключение к этому файлу. В функции `data_pd()` идет запись фрейма и сохранения в файл. Вот тут-то проблема и возникла. Из за то что в цикле идет подключение к таблице - `list_ = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_xlsx)`, записывается последняя запись (почему на это грешу, специально, один район, выводил эти строки за цикл и все прекрасно записывается (если таблица в директории существует), но если выводить за пределы цикла и удалить всю директорию, выдает ошибку (не найдена табл в директории), по этому не хочу убирать эти строки из цикла. Вот про какие строки имеется введу:

```
list_ = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_xlsx)
list_sheet = list_.active
list_sheet['A1'] = 'Кадастровый номер'
list_sheet['B1'] = 'Адрес'
list_sheet['C1'] = 'Площадь кв.м.'
list_sheet['D1'] = 'Инвентарный номер'
list_sheet['E1'] = 'Наименование'
list_sheet['F1'] = 'Этажность'
list_sheet['G1'] = 'Кадастровый номер родителя'
```

Строка - `if Name_MO()[0] == 'городской округ г. Выкса':` повторяется еще 50 раз и все что ниже нее тоже повторяется. Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать подключение к вновь созданной таблице и записать туда все данные?

Comment: Вам надо сохранять list_.save(file_xlsx) один раз вне цикла. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72681870/writing-multiple-sheets-in-same-workbook-using-for-loop

Comment: @Сергей Кох
 Увы, не получилось. Пробовал так написать:                                                                                  
 
        with pd.ExcelWriter(file_xlsx, engine='openpyxl', mode = 'a') as writer:
                                data_pd().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Инфа', index=False)

Comment: "Инфа" меняется в каждом цикле?

Comment: @Сергей Кох, **sheet_name='Инфа'** пусть остается, а вот данные из xml всегда разные и количество строк в таблице может быть также разным (они в функции **data_pd()**)

Comment: Если `sheet_name` не меняется, то каждый датафрейм перезаписывает ту же самую страницу, при использовании `to_excel`.

Comment: @Сергей Кох, даже в одном блоке **"городской округ г. Выкса"**, есть несколько xml файлов и разные данные из него, примеру: адрес - Выкса, ул, дзержинского, д.1; Выкса, ул, дзержинского, д.56 и т.д. Это просто для примера. Но, всегда последняя запись передается. Попробую убрать функцию **data_pd()** и перенести фрэйм в блок **"городской округ г. Выкса"**

Comment: Пробовал в самый конец записать код на запись excel. В общем, не реализуемо скорее всего. Переписывать код нужно по другому как то.

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать по другому, создать общий excel файл и записать туда все данные из xml с пометкой какой район к нему принадлежит. Не то что хотел первоначально, но что же...

---

Вот часть кода:

```html
if not os.path.isdir(r'minimushestvo\PDF'):
    os.makedirs(r'minimushestvo\PDF\plans\Excel')

if not os.path.isfile('list.xlsx'):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    dest_filename = 'list.xlsx'
    wb.save(os.path.join(r'minimushestvo\PDF\plans\Excel', dest_filename))
file_xlsx = r'minimushestvo\PDF\plans\Excel\list.xlsx'
list_ = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_xlsx)
list_sheet = list_.active
```

---

А дальше сделал простую запись в таблицу...:

```html
for r in dataframe_to_rows(data_pd(), index=False, header=False):
                    list_sheet.append(r)
                list_.save(file_xlsx)
```

---

Не хотелось бы этот ответ принимать, т.к. на мой вопрос не отвечает.